# How to filter duplicated dataframe by the minimum value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a program that takes in two identically formatted CSV files generated by a measurement machine. It combines the two files with a third CSV file of equal length that contains the rules for the two user-inputted CSV files.

The combined dataframe then goes through a function to determine which features (in this case index i) are far away enough from the nominal value that they require an offset to be applied. I have then split this new dataframe into a duplicated and non-duplicated list. The duplicated list (df_dup)is based on the subset of two columns being equal, the non-duplicated list is everything else that didn't make it to the duplicated list. I write this paragraph to explain why my dataframe will be different each time it's run.

What I want to do is go through df_dup and for each grouping (that is based on them having the same TOOL and AXIS column value) determine which row has the MIN "HI-TOLERANCE" column value and display that row as the representative. If multiple rows in the same grouping also have the same tolerance value, then I don't really care which is chosen. It can pick the first/last/whatever is easiest programmatically.

I've attempted to use groupby and transform based on another StackOverflow post, but it did not change my dataframe at all. This is the code I tried:

```
df_dup = df_dup[df_fdup['HI-TOL'] == df_dup.groupby('TOOL')['HI-TOLERANCE'].transform('min')]
```

I apologize if I've worded this vaguely and will elaborate as best I can. If anyone could point me in a direction, I basically want to filter my df_dup so that only one row from each grouping is selected based on the minimum value in another column.

Comment: Can you explain what is `df_fdup`? Also is the index of each column from `df_dup` enough for you to determinie what you need?

Comment: Whoops, that's a typo and should also say df_dup! the index of each column is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `idxmin` for that like so

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
idxmin = df.groupby(['TOOL', 'AXIS'])['HI-TOLERANCE'].idxmin()
print(df.loc[idxmin])
```

output

```
   TOOL  AXIS  HI-TOLERANCE
0     1     1             1
2     1     2             2
```

data.csv

```
TOOL,AXIS,HI-TOLERANCE
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 2, 2
1, 2, 4
1, 2, 5
```

Comment: Wow, that does exactly what I want it to do, thank you! I'll have to read more on idxmin/max, it looks very useful! This is my first program so everything is still very unfamiliar for me, but I'm making progress thanks to people like you (: